# How to use a transaction query mysql to keep it on for a few page in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I know how to using a transaction query in mysql and also commit or rollback. I want to make a portfolio of an application in my website. Some guest could try to use it, but when it end (either they logout or suddenly close the browser), i want all the query they've been made to be rollback so i dont have clean the database.

But then i found that start transaction is not long last when i hit a submit button in a form and move in to another page as usual. Is there anything i can do about it? To keep the transaction query ON/TRUE wherever page i landed.  Thanks (and sorry for my bad english language).

Answer (score 0):

You can create hidden inputs within your forms and have them store the data from the previous form or in PHP Session variables. At the end you can create the entire transaction and push it through.

Comment: Thanks for comment :)
But i still confuse of your idea to save all the input in PHP session variable since the application hold so much data and need to process with the database. And if i allow them to store the input in database, would it be unable to rollback again since the every single query (especially the insert, update and delete) will be permanent if we dont use start transaction query?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the database transactions being permanent. That's exactly what the database should do, rather try implementing a method to store legacy data that the user can revert to if needed. Instead of using "delete", use a delete flag. Instead of "update" on a record, create a new record with a version number and always read the newest number.

Comment: So, you can say its impossible to use transaction in here? :)

Comment: No, you can still use the transaction syntax if you'd like. Only, using this method, you're going to send the full "Transaction, Insert, Commit" at once.

Comment: I see. So far, your method is save than method i try to search. I read about persistent connection that maybe allow my transaction query over other page, but they said that its not recommend for several reason. I interesting for cache table, do you have any idea about that??

Comment: Cache tables improve performance when performing "Select" statements that use the same parameters. Your users will be creating a single portfolio over multiple pages, so you should store all their values in a Session variable that will be used when they get to the end. If they don't make it to the end, then their Session will end which will prevent the need for rollback.